# Can I search for a needle in my codebase that only appears within a string in phpStorm?

Tags: search, phpstorm

I want to search occurences of a string in my codebase. Alas, it appears both in variable names and within strings. I want to keep the variable names and change the occurrences in a string.

How to only search for a needle in a string?

Comment: It looks like you can use a regex for search-and-replace [Finding and Replacing Text in File](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html), so you just need to devise a regex which finds your variable name but not the same text when it is in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is special option available in PhpStorm v7 and newer (very easy to use):

**Find in Path** dialog (search across multiple files)
[image]

**Quick find** -- searches current file only:
[image]